# how to get Title Tab ViewPagerIndicator in activity?

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

i just learn library viewpagerindicator...
i want to ask, how how to get Title Tab ViewPagerIndicator in activity ?
this my fragment activity

```
 public static Fragment newInstance(Context _context) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ContentActivity activitynya = new ContentActivity();
                    return activitynya;
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tulisan_list, null);
                Intent in = getActivity().getIntent();


                   String Name_of_Tab = what ? ;
}
```

and code **String Name_of_Tab = what ?** , how get name of tab indicator ?

thanks guys, sorry for my english..

Comment: please provide more information like R.layout.tulisan_list content

Comment: R.layout.tulisan_list is layoutcontent activity...

Comment: i just want to get name of tab not to show in layout.. just initial variabel

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use  getPageTitle(int position) with the instance of your viewpagerindicator.

```
// Get a reference to the ViewPageIndicator
vpi = (ViewPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);

// Get the title
vpi.getPageTitle(int position);
```